# how to send message to azure bot in python via direct line service

Tags: python, botframework

We recently deployed a Bot to Azure with type User assigned managed identity, so I only have app id, but not app password. I am trying to send messages via the Direct Line service from a python app. Following are my code:

```
from botframework.connector.auth import MicrosoftAppCredentials
from botframework.connector.client import ConnectorClient

credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials("YOUR_CLIENT_ID", "")
base_url="https://directline.botframework.com/"
client = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url=base_url)

connectorClient = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url=base_url)
client.conversations.send_to_conversation(conversation_id, message, service_url=base_url)
```

The python package I installed is botframework-connector==4.14.0

I got an error about access_token. Can anyone help what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `request` library to send direct message to azure bot via direct line like this :

```
import requests

# Replace YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET with your bot's Direct Line secret
direct_line_secret = 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET'

# Set the headers for the request
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + direct_line_secret,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Set the parameters for the request
data = {
    'type': 'message',
    'from': {
        'id': 'YOUR_USER_ID'
    },
    'text': 'Hello, world!'
}

# Send the request to the Direct Line API
response = requests.post('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/YOUR_CONVERSATION_ID/activities', json=data, headers=headers)

# Print the response status code
print(response.status_code)
```

If you want a user-assigned managed identity to authenticate the BotFrameworkConnectorClient without specifying an app password.
Follow this :

```
import os
from botframework.connector import ConnectorClient
from botframework.connector.auth import AzureActiveDirectoryAuthentication

# Replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID and YOUR_TENANT_ID with your own values
CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
TENANT_ID = 'YOUR_TENANT_ID'

# Get the access token for the Bot Framework API
auth = AzureActiveDirectoryAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, TENANT_ID)
access_token = auth.get_access_token()

# Create a ConnectorClient
client = ConnectorClient(auth, base_url='https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline')

# Set the parameters for the request
conversation_id = 'YOUR_CONVERSATION_ID'
activity = {
    'type': 'message',
    'from': {
        'id': 'YOUR_USER_ID'
    },
    'text': 'Hello, world!'
}

# Send the message
response = client.conversations.send_to_conversation(conversation_id, activity)

# Print the response
print(response)
```

or you could use `ManagedIdentityCredential`

```
import os
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from botframework.connector import ConnectorClient

# Set the resource and tenant ID
RESOURCE = "https://directline.botframework.com"
TENANT_ID = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"

# Create a ManagedIdentityCredential
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(resource=RESOURCE, tenant_id=TENANT_ID)

# Create a ConnectorClient
client = ConnectorClient(credential, base_url='https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline')

# Set the parameters for the request
conversation_id = 'YOUR_CONVERSATION_ID'
activity = {
    'type': 'message',
    'from': {
        'id': 'YOUR_USER_ID'
    },
    'text': 'Hello, world!'
}

# Send the message
response = client.conversations.send_to_conversation(conversation_id, activity)

# Print the response
print(response
```

)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you know if there is way to achieve this using botframework-connector. Because we have old bots created without the type (User assigned managed identity), which we have the passwords and above code works well.

Comment: Hum... I don't have AzureActiveDirectoryAuthentication in botframework.connector.auth?

Comment: you could use ManagedIdentityCredential from azure.identity

Comment: Thanks. I installed  azure-identity==1.5.0, since the latest version I got an error. But I still got an error while sending adaptive card to Bot:  Exception occurred while sending proactive message: 'ManagedIdentityCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'

Comment: Actually the error is ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found. Do I need to config anything in Azure portal?

Comment: @GLP Using the requests library is how I would do it. It works with both managed identity and multi-tenant bots.

Comment: I marked this as answer because at certain context, it is the right answer. This is from chatGPT, If your Python app is hosted on Google Cloud, it will not be able to use a managed identity from Azure Active Directory (AAD) for authentication. Managed identities are specific to Azure and are used to authenticate with Azure services.